# To implement expand/ collapse on table rows

Tags: jquery, html-table

My table looks like this

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><div><span class='level2'>Header1</span></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div><span class='level3'>Data1</span></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div><span class='level3'>Data2</span></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div><span class='level2'>Header2</span></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div><span class='level3'>Data21</span></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div><span class='level3'>Data22</span></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I need to implement expand/collapse, I want all the level3 `<tr>`'s to be grouped under level2 `<tr>`'s

I could implement it if the class property is tagged to  (ex: `<tr class="level2">`) but when it is tagged to its children I am not sure how to club them.

My try with tr having a class property is

```
$('.level2').click(function(){
$(this).nextUntil('tr.level2').slideToggle(100);
});
```

Need help for my current table structure case.

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
$('.level2').click(function(){
$(this).closest('tr').next('tr').slideToggle(100);});
```

Comment: No, it didn't work. It just groups the next <tr>, but I want it to club all the <tr>'s that under the current <tr> till it encounters a new <tr> that has a similar children style.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was difficult to understand... as now what I have understood...
try this...

```
$('tr.level2').click(function(){
 $(this).nextUntil("tr.level2").slideToggle(100);});
```